# iOS: TabBar controller above UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a problem with my tab bar placed above my view
I am using iOS 8 and Autolayout

I have my main view which has a button that opens another view that has the tab bar:

```
-(IBAction)btnOpen:(id)sender
{

            Home* homevc = [[Home alloc] initWithNibName:@"Home_iPhone" bundle:nil];

            UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homevc];
            [nc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Home"];
            [nc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon.png"]];


            Search *searchvc = [[Search alloc] initWithNibName:@"Search_iPhone" bundle:nil];
            [searchvc.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Search"];
            [searchvc.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_icon.png"]];

            UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
            [tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nc,searchvc, nil]];

            UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:191/255.0f green:50/255.0f blue:46/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

            [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:color];
            [[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]
                                                     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
            [self presentViewController:tabController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

How can I place the Home view above the tab bar?

Comment: Bassically UITabBarController is made to be parent of any ViewController. As apple you can add a NavigationController over TabBatController. All NavigationControllers must part of `tabBar.viewControllers`. So you can't. But you can trick it. Use a ViewController with NavigationController. Add tabBar over ViewController , hide navigationController's navigation bar.

Comment: @HarvantS. Thanks but can you please show me some code or elaborate more I can't seem to get what you mean. I already have a navigation controller in my view controller that I am using I don't what it hidden but what do you mean add the tab bar over view controller?